# mysql join 1:2 relation

Tags: mysql, join, relation

I am sitting and and thinkig about a solution for a 1:2 relation problem:
2 tables (more complex, but the source problem is easier to understand).

table 1 machines

```
id | name | location_id | manufacturar_id | ...
```

table 2 partners

```
id | address | name | firstname | companyname | ...
```

I would like to get sothing out like:

```
jigsaw xpy123 | super-carpenter, mainstreet 12, (location, partner-table) | GE wood servcies, x-street, Maine (manufacturer)
```

Basicly, it should be two querys:

```
select handelspartner.name as hersteller 
from handelspartner,anlagen 
where anlagen.hersteller_id=handelspartner.id

select handelspartner.name as standort 
from handelspartner,anlagen 
where anlagen.standort_id=handelspartner.id
```

But this should be somehow possible in one query?

Comment: It's really confusing when you change the names of everything between the diagram of the tables and the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Aliases for the table handelspartner.

```
select handelspartner1.name as hersteller, handelspartner2.name as standort 
from anlagen 
join handelspartner handelspartner1 on anlagen.hersteller_id=handelspartner1.id
join handelspartner handelspartner2 on anlagen.standort_id=handelspartner2.id
```